# Is this the correct use of "catalogue"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

**Example:** He came up with a catalogue of things his father said or did which upset him.

Is the use of "catalogue" correct in this example? I personally think so, as the word derives from the Greek καταλέγω, which means to "recount, to tell at length, or make a list" [(1)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catalogue#English).

I wanted to use a word that is slightly stronger than *list*, as *catalogue* conveys a carefully constructed list in which we place importance. Obviously, this list is important to the son.

What are your thoughts? They would be much appreciated.

---

**Update:**

I simply feel that the etymology of "catalogue" helps us understand its nuances. That's why I reproduced it. This does not hold true for every word. But I never said it held true for every word. In the cases where it *does*, I think it's interesting to learn the etymology.

Comment: People use it that way all the time...

Comment: Yes, it is normal; but your argument from Greek is [irrelevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

Comment: @Colin Fine Actually, what I gave wasn't an argument, it was a reason for thinking so. Why not share things we find interesting?

Comment: Yes it was. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQFKtI6gn9Y

Comment: An argument makes a claim. It attempts to persuade. I did neither. I simply shared my hypothesis.

Comment: And I am pointing out (by the link I referenced) that your hypothesis is without foundation. If you rely on etymology to determine (as opposed to suggest) the meanings of words, you will often get them wrong.

Comment: @Colin Fine Hypotheses don't need foundations. Conclusions need foundations. In this case, my hypothesis turned out to be correct, so I was justified in pursuing my hypothesis.

Comment: All Colin Fine is saying is that relying solely on etymology for the present day meaning or usage of a word is living dangerously.

Comment: @ab2 All I'm saying is that etymology is an interesting feature of every word. See my post update.

Comment: @ktm5124 Agreed.

Comment: @ab2 It's as if I said that "4" is a perfect square. This statement doesn't mean that every integer is a perfect square. You simply can't accuse someone of generalizing... when they don't generalize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, catalogue is used with the meaning you are suggesting, usually in relation  to bad/negative things:

***[catalogue](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catalogue)*** noun (bad events)

> - A catalogue of unwanted events is a series of them:
>
>   - *The whole holiday was a catalogue of disasters.
>       a catalogue of errors/crimes/complaints*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 3):

I think that's correct, although perhaps a bit unusual. I agree that a catalogue can be any kind of systematic, carefully constructed list, not just a list of items sold at a store or a list of books in a library. Merriam-Webster includes this definition: "a complete enumeration of items arranged systematically with descriptive details." And the New Oxford American Dictionary includes "a complete list of items, typically one in alphabetical or other systematic order."

I think however that when using "catalogue" to describe less standard kinds of lists it's perhaps a little more common to use "catalogue" as a verb, e.g., "He catalogued all the things his father said or did that upset him." That sounds more natural to me, although I don't think it makes much difference.